# Getting different result from AIX java code reading special chars

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, aix

I am getting different result running my java code from AIX.

```
public class TestChars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "…";
        for(char c: s.toCharArray())
            System.out.println(" Character Name : " + Character.getName(c) + " Simbol : '"+c+"' Code : " + Integer.toHexString((int)c));
    }
}
```

**AIX:**

```
Character Name : LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX Simbol : '?' Code : e2
Character Name : LATIN 1 SUPPLEMENT 80 Simbol : '?' Code : 80
Character Name : BROKEN BAR Simbol : '?' Code : a6
```

**But here is the expected result:**

```
Character Name : HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS Simbol : '…' Code : 2026
```

I'm still unclear where the problem is or what is needed to make ibm java version from aix give the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not AIX-specific: the compiler assumes that the input is in ISO-8859-x, but it is actually in UTF-8

Possible solutions:

```
#1: LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 javac TestChars.java
#2: javac -encoding UTF-8 TestChars.java
```

Also you can use \u sequences in the source:

```
String s = "\u2026";
```

Comment: Great. It works! 
I just compiled using the encoding parameter. Thanks a lot Lorinczy.